# can not get access to the ASP.NET MVC controller method with [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] even after login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Implemented Identity, and I've stared it from scratch. I've created a login method in controller and I'm getting login through an JavaScript AJAX call. 
But when I try to access a controller method which has a `Authorize(Roles = "Admin")` I can not do that and every time it send me to the UnAuthorize page 401

*Why I'm not able to get access to the Controller method I've `user with same admin role` every thing as accordingly, whats wrong with my login process, and my login page is not a strongly type View*

Here is my controller method

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Create()
{
return View();
}
```

My Login method

```
public string ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
        userStore.Context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString =
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;

        var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

        // create user and save tahat to the db
        var user = manager.Find(userName, password);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           // var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(userName, password);
            if (user != null)
            {
            //sign in user
                authenticationManger.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = false
                }, userIdentity);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }
        return userName;
    }
```

This is my ajax call to the login method

```
function ValidateUser() {
        debugger;
        var userName = document.getElementById('username').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        var url = "/Public/ValidateUser/";
        $("#btnLogin").val('Plesae wait..');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { UserName: userName, Password: password },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === userName && userName !== "") {
                    //alert("Successfull login.");
                    location.href = "/Home/Index";
                } else {
                    $(".alert").show();//.delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
                    setTimeout(function () { $(".alert").fadeOut(); }, 2000);
                    //location.href = "/Public/login";
                }
                $("#username").attr({ 'value': '' });
                $("#password").attr({ 'value': '' });
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
        $("#btnLogin").val('Login');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

**UPDATE**

This line of code returns true

```
var useris = manager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Admin");
```

and This line of code returns false

```
           var user= User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

What is wrong Please!

Comment: do you have the role "Admin" assigned to the user?

Comment: @Ziyad yes as I mentioned in my question

Comment: is the cookie being stored? perhaps your javascript login process is not storing the cookie, therefore when you navigate to `create` the cookie is not being set correctly. you should try cookieless sessions, and see if that points you in the right direction. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx)

Comment: @Jim yes I've tried this too but its still not authorizing me 
`var authenticationManger = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
                    var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
`

Comment: Please share the code for userIdentity that is used in authenticationManger.SignIn()

Comment: @MarcusH they are all `Microsoft.Owin.Security` classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the user I created before extending my `OWIN` to `role` based and `group` based Authorization became null and void so I'd to add this new line every time I create a new user its `SecurtyStamp` needed to be updated like this

> `await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);`

Hope this helps any one

Answer (score 0):

your code contains some typos and it is not clear!

for example, the below code is only for finding a user not for creating;

```
// create user and save tahat to the db
var user = manager.Find(userName, password);
```

also `authenticationManger` should start with capital letter, and where is `userIdentity` coming from?

```
AuthenticationManger.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
{
   IsPersistent = false
}, userIdentity);
```

try it with SignInManager like below:

```
public string ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
{
    var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(userName, password, false, false);
    if(result==SignInStatus.Success)
        return userName;

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
        //return View(model);
        return View();
}
```

Comment: if I do it your way I get this error `An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Value cannot be null.`

Comment: Make sure the userName and password has values

Comment: Just noticed that yiu are using Capital letters for UserName and Password in your ajax call, and small letters in the method variables userName and password! variable names should be same !

Comment: my love as I said I get the username and password and as you can see
this line of code works perfectly and return a perfect value 
`var user = manager.Find(userName, password);`